# how can i update php cli version from command prompt on Windows?

Tags: php, command-prompt

i am using windows os, want to update php version to **PHP 7.2.5** or grater
currently using PHP 7.2.3

Comment: Install new PHP version, then, if not done automatic, update the environment variable

Comment: Thanks, I updated PHP version, but not changes, How can i change environment verialble ?

Comment: you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0)

Comment: okay Great!
which directory or file i should set in variable path ?

Comment: the new php executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update the PHP installed version
2. Update the environmental variable with the path of the newly installed PHP folder ([info here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0))
3. Restart any console already open in order to refresh the state
4. (in some cases/software restart the pc)